# Can't retrieve certain cookies with PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I've got to be missing something simple, but this is driving me batty.

I'm setting a whole bunch of array cookies, like so:

```
setcookie("adjusted[$title]", $title, time() + 3600, "/", ".domain.com");
```

This works just fine, the cookies are being set and I can see them in the browser's cookie list.

However, I can't seem to read only certain values back out!  I have no idea why.  For example, I set this cookie:

```
adjusted[calldelivernow.net]
```

and I can see that is its name in Firefox's cookies page, the content is "calldelivernow.net".  But all attempts to do this return false:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["adjusted"]["calldelivernow.net"]))
    die("Cookie is set");
```

This is just one example of many, all under identical parameters just with different domain names.  What on earth am I missing here?  How can a cookie plainly exist in the browser, yet PHP not be able to read it?

Answer (score 4):

Because you're not calling it by it's name correctly. Unlike form names, cookies do not get stacked to arrays.

Try `$_COOKIE["adjusted[calldelivernow.net]"]`.

Comment: No change whatsoever, just returns false.  =(

Comment: @Jonathan: Try `var_dump()`ing your `$_COOKIE` superglobal to see what's actually in there

Comment: I already have, it's loaded with cookies, but NOT the ones that are missing, despite them clearly appearing in Firefox.  These missing cookies are also reset if I delete them all and run my setting script again.  So they ARE definitely being set.

Comment: @JonathanvanClute: View the request in the browser console, are the cookies being sent to the server at all?

Comment: Yes, because many of them are being set, and are perfectly retrievable.  There are just certain ones (as in the example above) that don't get set.  Everything is being done in a loop so if any get set, they should all get set.  And according to Firefox they ARE.

Comment: @JonathanvanClute: Please post a full reproducible test-case. The minimal amount of code that shows the problem clearly.

Comment: I'll see what I can come up with as far as a simplest test case.  In the meantime for what it's worth, this absolutely does not work: `if(isset($_COOKIE['adjusted[internetwebfinder.net]']))
 die(var_dump($_COOKIE));` but this does: `if(isset($_COOKIE['adjusted']['internetwebfinder.net']))
 die(var_dump($_COOKIE));`

Comment: Well I don't think it can get any simpler than this... `setcookie("calldelivernow.net", "calldelivernow.net", time() + 3600, "/", ".domain.com");
if(isset($_COOKIE["calldelivernow.net"]))
 die(var_dump($_COOKIE));
else
 die ('nope');` This fails every time (changing domain.com to the domain the script is running on of course), although the cookie is being set according to firefox.

Comment: UPDATE - changing the name and content of the cookie to "test" works fine.  So what gives??

Comment: OK, the problem ONLY arises when the name of the cookie, is a domain name.  If the name is "test" and the content is a domain name, it works fine.  But it the name is a domain name and the content is "test", it fails.

Comment: Bingo!  Can't have periods in cookie names!  It's appearing with the period in firefox, but actually in `$_COOKIE` it's: `["calldelivernow_net"]=> string(4) "test"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that cookie names, cannot contain periods!  Strangely, Firefox is in fact showing that the cookie name is correct and contains the period, but the `$_COOKIE` array replaces the period with an underscore, like so:  `["calldelivernow_net"]=> string(4) "test"`